# Minecraft Username Connection

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am on the Hypixel Minecraft server with my friends. I just changed my username last night. I have logged back in, reloaded the launcher, but I still cant get in any multiplayer servers. It says "failed to authenticate connection" or "Unidentified Username"

Comment: DOes this happen to any other server?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this problem resolved itself when I logged out of the launcher. Never mind!

Comment: It would be best to word this more like an answer.